# How can I apply the :active pseudoclass to multiple elements at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>

<style>
#a, #b, #c {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#a:active, #b:active, #c:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

When I click on #a, only #a changes color, when I click on #b, only #b changes color, and when I click on #c, only #c changes color.

What can I do so that when I click #a OR #b OR #c, all of them change color at the same time?

I do not know if the solution requires JS, but if it does, please answer using vanilla JS

Comment: I don't think you can explicitly add psuedo-classes; they are activated when you interact with a page. Why not use regular classes, such as `#a.active`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JavaScript or JQuery. You can achieve this using only CSS.

Here's how.

1. Nest all the elements in a parent element, and add the same class to all the children.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="a" class="abc">A</div>
    <div id="b" class="abc">B</div>
    <div id="c" class="abc">C</div>
</div>
```

2. Use the `:has()` pseudo selector to check if any of the children are active and then, apply the properties to all the children if anyone is active.

```
#main:has(.abc:active) > .abc {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: In a situation where all child elements are targeted, this can be simplified using the child and universal selectors: `#main:has(> *:active) > * { }`

Comment: Yes, this would be ideal if you want to target all the elements inside an element.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely need JavaScript (or jQuery) to accomplish this. Here is a simple way to do it with event listeners.

The code below will apply a class to all elements when one of them is clicked and then remove it when the click is released.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#a, #b, #c');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
      elements[j].classList.add('active');
    }
  });

  elements[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
      elements[j].classList.remove('active');
    }
  });

  elements[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
      elements[j].classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

#a, #b, #c {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
```

Comment: You are not using :active, and also you are not explaining why you don't use :active.